# Pandas Dataframes- Adding Fields Based on Column Titles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with some information in the column titles that I want to add to each row. The dataframe looks like:

```
print working_df

  Retail Sales of Electricity : Arkansas : Industrial : Annual  \
Year                                                                 
0                                           16709.19272              
1                                           16847.75502              
2                                           16993.92202              
3                                           16774.69902              
4                                           14710.29400          

  Retail Sales of Electricity : Arizona : Residential : Annual  \
Year                                                                 
0                                           33138.47860              
1                                           32922.97001              
2                                           33079.07402              
3                                           32448.13802              
4                                           32846.84298     

[8 rows x 701 columns]
```

How can I pull out two variables from the column name (the state, e.g. Arizona, and the sector, e.g. Industrial or Residential) and put them as a value the row in two new columns, respectively?

I would like the to have fields that look like

```
Year      State              Sector                      Sales                       
0         Arizona            Residential                 33138.47860              
1         Arizona            Residential                 32922.97001              
2         Arizona            Residential                 33079.07402              
3         Arizona            Residential                 32448.13802              
4         Arizona            Residential                 32846.84298    
0         Arkansas           Industrial                  16709.19272              
1         Arkansas           Industrial                  16847.75502              
2         Arkansas           Industrial                  16993.92202              
3         Arkansas           Industrial                  16774.69902              
4         Arkansas           Industrial                  14710.29400
```

Comment: Could you give an (abbreviated) example of what you want the output structure to look like?

Comment: Thanks @DSM, I edited the post with a abbreviated version of my desired output structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'd do something like

```
d2 = df.unstack().reset_index()
d2 = d2.rename(columns={0: "Sales"})
parts = d2.pop("level_0").str.split(":")
d2["State"] = [p[1].strip() for p in parts]
d2["Sector"] = [p[2].strip() for p in parts]
```

which produces

```
>>> d2
   Year        Sales     State       Sector
0     0  16709.19272  Arkansas   Industrial
1     1  16847.75502  Arkansas   Industrial
2     2  16993.92202  Arkansas   Industrial
3     3  16774.69902  Arkansas   Industrial
4     4  14710.29400  Arkansas   Industrial
5     0  33138.47860   Arizona  Residential
6     1  32922.97001   Arizona  Residential
7     2  33079.07402   Arizona  Residential
8     3  32448.13802   Arizona  Residential
9     4  32846.84298   Arizona  Residential

[10 rows x 4 columns]
```

You could be a little fancier and do something with `str.extract` -- `str.extract(r".*?:\s*(?P<State>.*?)\s*:\s*(?P<Sector>.*?)\s*:.*")`, maybe -- but I don't think it's really worth it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DSM; I follow what you do in the first three lines. But I'm getting a list index out of range error on the last two lines that actually create the new column. Any thoughts?

Comment: @John: that must mean that you have columns which don't match the pattern that you showed me.  Loop over them and see which ones are different, e.g. `print([p for p in parts if len(p) != 4])`.

Comment: @DSML Hmmm, your suggested print statement doesn't return anything. I scrolled through the output of parts and it all seems to be very consistent in pattern, e.g.     309,"[u'Retail Sales of Electricity ', u' California ', u' Industrial ', u' Annual']"
310,"[u'Retail Sales of Electricity ', u' California ', u' Industrial ', u' Annual']"      although I'm sure it is some problem on my end, as your code makes sense.

Comment: Got it working, I was working in an IPython notebook and just had to reset some variables in another part of the notebook. Thanks again, I'll definitely remember that approach in the future.